# install librosa on raspberry pi 4, error with the wheel of llvmlite

Tags: python, llvm, librosa, raspberry-pi4, llvmlite

Im working on raspberry pi 4, with Python3 and I want to install librosa. (`pip3 install librosa`)

Previously I installed llvm version 7.0.1

Following the Compatibility I install llvmlite https://pypi.org/project/llvmlite/

```
$ LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config pip3 install llvmlite=0.32.0
```

That block during the instalation of librosa or numba

```
Building wheel for llvmlite (setup.py) ... error
```

If someone has advice about how solve it, thank you to give me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got mine running by installing `llvmlite==0.31.0`, `numba==0.48.0`, `librosa==0.6.3`, `colorama==0.3.9`.

Command:

```sh
# specify a valid dependency tree with pi compatibility
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config pip3 install llvmlite==0.31.0 numba==0.48.0 colorama==0.3.9 librosa==0.6.3
```

**Note**: `colorama` is used only to show colored output in the console, if the package causes you issues try removing it but otherwise keep it otherwise you will have errors while importing the module.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  Machael, is working !    Any way if someone didn't success to get librosa lib, with matplotlib spectogram are available. (using:  pxx, freq, t, cax = ax.specgram(frames, Fs=rate, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin))

Comment: I got this to work on a raspberry pi zero 2 w by first running `sudo apt-get -y install llvm-8` then `pip install Cython` and then using `LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-8` at the start. It took a long time to install, but eventually worked.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Michael S. !

But actually the command should be:

```
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config pip3 install llvmlite==0.31.0 numba==0.48.0 colorama==0.3.9 librosa==0.6.3
```

it should be == in:

> llvmlite=0.31.0